# React Native: how to grab an instance, use ID, UUID, Ref?

Tags: reactjs, expo, native, jsx

I am new to React Native, suppose I have the following:

```
<View id='z'>
   <Input id='x'/>
   <Button id='y'/>
</View>
```

In jQuery, I would:

```
$('#x').val('xxxx');
console.log($('#z Input').title);
```

How can I do this in React Native way? How to give the instance a handle so I can grab it and get many thing from it?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

if you only need the value, try this way,

```
<View>
  <Input onChangeText={text=>this.setState({inputBox:text})} />
  <Button onPress={()=>console.log("value",this.state.inputBox)}/>
</View>
```